# Should I use static_cast in assignments and return statements and why?

Tags: c++, casting, static-cast

Here are two very similar snippets:

```
vector<int> a;
int n = static_cast<int>(a.size());
// ---------
int f(const vector<int>& a) {
    return static_cast<int>(a.size());
}
```

Here I explicitly cast a value of type `size_t` to type `int`. If I omit `static_cast` then the same cast applies implicitly.

Of which kind would this implicit cast be? Is it safe to omit `static_cast` in explicit assignments and return statements?

Comment: I would prefer to change the type of n and return type of f so cast will be not-necessary. But if you must to use incompatible type - explicit cast is prefferebale to show that something fishy is happening at this line. And proper compiler with high level warnig settings will not let this code to compile without cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cast is not that safe, actualy the value of `n` may be implementation defined (c++ standard [conv.integral]):

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

If you enable all warning, and don't use the static_cast, your compiler may inform you about a narrowing conversion. If you use the `static_cast`, you inform reader of your code that you know for sure that `a.size() <= std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` or that you know what your implementation is going to do if such a condition does not hold.

(notice that it could be possible that previous comparison also invokes implementation defined conversion if std::size_t is smaller than int, the c++ standard allowes it)

Comment: This answer better explains what's going on here instead of suggesting other best practices. I appreciate, but by the means of this question I was peculiarly interested in details of this behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov :), I was just reading CppCoreGuidelines and they propose to implement a narrow_cast for this specific cast. Also, there is a function `narrow`, that check in debug mode that the conversion does not change the value, https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/gsl_util

Answer (score 4):

This would be an integral conversion. And a narrowing one at that.

For the variable initialization, if you want a specific type, a good approach is to do what Herb Sutter suggests in his "Almost Always Auto" [GotW article](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/):

```
auto n = int{a.size()};
```

Use list initialization whenever possible. It will prevent narrowing conversions and you'll be flagged by your compiler to use an explicit cast when required (such as the case above).

Answer (score 2):

The necessarily of casting is determined by the necessarily of conversion. So the real question here should "be why would I return / store an `int` instead of `vector<int>::size_type`?" If your program logic doesn't really require such conversion then don't perform it at all. If your program logic requires such conversion (for example you need to pass this value into a call to a third-party function that accepts `int`) then you should use `static_cast`. Omitting `static_cast` in this case would be a sign of unintended narrowing conversion and will trigger corresponding compiler warnings, such as `warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data` or `warning: conversion to 'int' from 'std::vector<int>::size_type {aka long unsigned int}' may alter its value [-Wconversion]`